# How to use webview flutter with proxy?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, proxy

I'm using [Webview Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package to embed some websites to my flutter project. For some websites I need to use proxy server (ip:port) to connect (country access restrictions). How can I add proxy server to my project and use Webview Flutter package through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Flutter ignores your device settings for proxy, so you'll need to override it within your Flutter app like so:

```
class MyProxyHttpOverride extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..findProxy = (uri) {
        return "PROXY localhost:8888;";
      }
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

// In your main.dart
HttpOverrides.global = MyProxyHttpOverride();
```

Of course, you'll need to change `localhost:8888` to whatever your proxy settings are - and likely in your case this will have to be dynamic that the user can change.

I wrote a more detailed write up about this solution [here](https://medium.com/hoursofoperation/use-charles-proxy-to-debug-network-requests-in-flutter-apps-2f2083275cad) - although this is about getting it to work with Charles Proxy, the overall problem and solution is the same.

Comment: Is there any source for the proxy schema you used?

Comment: is it possible to apply proxy selectively on only certain requests?

Comment: If you mean regular requests, then you can use something like Dio combined with onHttpClientCreate. You could have two separate Dio clients: one with and one without proxy support. See an example here for enable proxy with Dio: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/proxy.dart

Comment: @Aron are you sure your answer also works for WebView and not only for http requests made directly? The OP has asked a solution for WebView and I have tested your solution in the same WebView as mentioned by OP, and it does not work (works for api calls).

Comment: At the time it worked - if it still does...I'm not sure...